# How to modify firebase offline data via android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

The android app I am currently developing will mainly run offline. However while online, the users can connect to the DB to download the data they need. Furthermore they are able to manage the data offline, so they can remove the data they don't want to use. The users cannot modify the online database.
I am using Firebase with its Persistence enabled feature, to save the date for online use. My problem is, that I just cannot manage the data properly.

Since firebase downloads the whole database:
Is there a way to choose, which queries I want to download form firebase? 
If not, can I delete those queries I don't want to use, from local content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you don't want the sync feature of the firebase database.

> However while online, the users can connect to the DB to download the
>   data they need. Furthermore they are able to manage the data offline,
>   so they can remove the data they don't want to use. The users cannot
>   modify the online database.

set write as false for this table in the rules and the modification will not be possible, since you have enabled disk persistence firebase will read the newer updates but wont write the user changes. Also it might discard the existing changes of the user(which the user removed) during the sync and put the newer ones from the cloud, **so you might(as I have never tried this)** end up doing the sync yourself, please search and read up on this.

> Since firebase downloads the whole database: Is there a way to choose,
>   which queries I want to download form firebase? If not, can I delete
>   those queries I don't want to use, from local content?

You will have to **turn off on the sync on the each of your table** like shown below

```
DatabaseReference dbRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("table-name");
dbRef.keepSynced(false);
```

Refer here in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities). I think this has to be done on each node as there is no way to turn it off on the entire firebase realtime DB except disable disk persistance which you want in your case.

IMHO it looks like you are using firebase as a place to store your data in the cloud, **in case the sync feature ends up discarding your local changes** to sync the online ones you should consider using SQL-lite DB with Room ORM as it will serve your purpose of just fetching the data and modifying it locally, however the tradeoff here is that you will have to maintain the data in a proper manner to query the newer changes or see if there is any updates/deletes on any of the older records.

Comment: Good idea, I am going to use SQL-lite to store the data on my device. To prevent useless parsing, I will use gson to create json strings and store them in the database.